# Django migrate fail after adding new field or modifying an existing one but I don't want to delete my DB columns

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have to things that bother me and make me wondering if I really understood django or not.

first of all I changed a little thing in my model :

```
article_country = models.ManyToManyField(Country, verbose_name=_('Country of the article'),
                                 blank=True, null=True,
                                 related_name='regions_press_article')
```

The related name became :
`related_name='country_press_article')`

And when I try to migrate I have this adorable error :

```
Unapplying djangocms_press.0002_auto_20160229_1136...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/management/__init__.py", line 41, in new_execute
return original_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 161, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 70, in migrate
self.unapply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 122, in unapply_migration
migration.unapply(project_state, schema_editor)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 157, in unapply
operation.database_backwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 144, in database_backwards
self.database_forwards(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 139, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 460, in alter_field
return self._alter_many_to_many(model, old_field, new_field, strict)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 759, in _alter_many_to_many
new_field.rel.through._meta.get_field_by_name(new_field.m2m_reverse_field_name())[0],
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 470, in alter_field
self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type, old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 478, in _alter_field
fk_names = self._constraint_names(model, [old_field.column], foreign_key=True)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 886, in _constraint_names
constraints = self.connection.introspection.get_constraints(cursor, model._meta.db_table)
File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/introspection.py", line 149, in get_constraints
"foreign_key": tuple(used_cols[0].split(".", 1)) if kind.lower() == "foreign key" else None,
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I was like "ok never mind it's not important, let's go to the next task and simply add a new Charfield to the model :

```
global_name = models.CharField(_('Global Name'), max_length=310, null=True)
```

(I precise that I undo my country change and deleted the migration file linked to it)

And what happening ? *Same error showing with the migrate command.*

**Why is it so complicate to do so little modifications in a model? How to solve it?**

Oh, by the way, I already solved this kind or problems by doing ./manage.py migrate myapp zero.

**But this time I don't want to delete my app DB!**

Comment: You get the same error because, once you have created a migration, any other later migrations will be performed only after that migration is done ( Based on the migration number).

Comment: Sorry, in fact I didn't precise that I removed my change, delete the first migrations (about region to country) and then create the other field. I edited it.

Comment: `related_name` is a name Django uses, I don't think it is applied to the database. Which `gettext` function are you using? Lazy or just `ugettext()`? About the migration, you'll need to delete from both database and the files inside your app > migration folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ev, I use ugettext_lazy